# SharePoint 2013 Workflow not triggering

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I set up workflow manager server and now my sharepoint 2013 can use 2013 workflows. I created a test workflow and I set the triggers to run when an item is created or updated. The problem is when I try it, the workflow is not triggering. It still shows 0 instances running, and in the workflow column in the list, nothing shows there.

What can I do to figure out whats not working? Also the 2010 version works fine. If I try to run manually, it still does not work.

Thanks

Comment: Is your user profile sync active and working?

Comment: I never set up user profile service on my farm. Also this is a dev environment not production. But why would this be needed for workflow?

Comment: Workflow 2013 uses REST in order to utilize communication with the workflow farm, since workflow 2013 doesn't need SharePoint. You need to have a working user profile association and a user profile for the service accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow 2013 uses REST in order to utilize communication with the workflow farm, since workflow 2013 doesn't need SharePoint. You need to have a working user profile association and a user profile for the service accounts.

Excerpt from [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx#section7)

> "The user who deploys and runs a workflow must be added to the User
>   Profile service. Check the User Profile service application page in
>   Central Administration to confirm that the user you are using to
>   validate workflow installation is in the User Profile service."

Comment: Hmm, didn't know this. +1. Any source for "workflow uses REST"?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193504.aspx